# Get multiple values from strut2 iterator

Tags: struts2, iterator, hibernate3, multiple-value

I am new to struts. I dont know exactly if my solution for my problem is correct or not.
My problem is I have two tables as shown below

[image: relation tables]

I would like to create an HTML table based on the above tables, showing the fields, name of group, id of group, and name of sub group and Id of subgroup. I tried to use list and iterator. But am not able to get both the values(both name and id)

inside class

```
public List getName() {
    return namesHead;
}

public void setName(List name) {
    this.namesHead = name;
}

public String listModules() {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateLoginUtil.getFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Query q1 = session.createQuery ("select id,name FROM TableUsrModuleGroup WHERE stat='active'");
    for(Iterator it = q1.iterate() ; it.hasNext() ;) {
         Object row[] = (Object[]) it.next();
         namesHead.add (row[1]); //put the name
    }   
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

in JSP page

```
<table>
  <s:iterator  status="status" value="namesHead" >   
  <tr><td><s:property/></td></tr>
  </s:iterator>
</table>
```

(only name of group can i get from the above code, I need to display group name, group Id, and name of sub group and Id of sub group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Hibernate, I think that the simplest option is to map the two classes and then recover both with a HQL query. For instance:

```
public class Group {
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection <SubGroup> subgroup;
    ... // Rest of the class, getters and setters
}

public class SubGroup {
    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Group group;
    ... // Rest of the class, getters and setters
}
```

Then you have to make this HQL query to get the `Group` class:

```
Query q = session.createQuery ("FROM SubGroup");
List<SubGroup> subgroups = (List<SubGroup>) q.list();
```

Then you set an attribute with the subgroups in the Action  and then you access to them in the jsp.

```
<table>
   <s:iterator  value="subgroups" >   
   <tr>
      <td>
          <s:property value="name"/>
      </td>

      <td>
          <s:property value="id"/>
      </td>

      <td>
          <s:property value="group.name"/>
      </td>

      <td>
          <s:property value="group.id"/>
      </td>
   </tr>
   </s:iterator>
</table>
```

I hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch object, not specific fields from database. You must have getter and setters for that object in your action, then in JSP you can get all properties of that object (don't forget setters/getters for object).